# Can I modify Excel Online share URLs to open to a specific worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, onedrive

When I generate a share URL in [Excel Online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx), it takes the following form:

```
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?
  resid=<DOCUMENT ID>&
  ithint=file%2cxlsx&
  app=Excel&
  authkey=<AUTH KEY>
```

Is there a parameter I can add to this URL so that it will open up to a specific worksheet within my document?

## Edit

Thanks to @mk117 for suggesting the following approach in the comments.

I can confirm that the following additions to the `ithint` parameter **do not work** (assume disired worksheet name is 'Chart'):

- `ithint=file%2cxlsx#'Chart'&`
- `ithint=file%2cxlsx#'!Chart'&`
- `ithint=file%2cxlsx#Chart&`
- `ithint=file%2cxlsx#!Chart&`

Comment: You could try and add `#Sheet3` to the `ithint` parameter... something similar to this line: `ithint=file%2cxlsx#'Sheet3'&` ... [source](http://word.tips.net/T000305_Hyperlinking_to_a_Specific_Excel_Worksheet.html)

Answer (score 9):

It works if you set active cell in the link, and specify sheet and cell. Try adding `&activeCell=%27Sheet1%27!A1` to the URL, where `Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet you're linking to, and `!A1` is the name of the cell on this worksheet.

Comment: Note: this appears to also require that you set `&action=embedview`, at least I couldn't get it to work without that action parameter.

Comment: Followup: &action=default works if the default is to use Office Online. Also, the sheet name must be wrapped in single quotes if it contains non-word characters.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for both **selecting the worksheet** and **selecting an active cell** when the sheet name has **no spaces**. However, if the sheet name has spaces, I can get to the worksheet (with or without quotations), but it does not select the cell if the sheet name has spaces.

yourlinkhere.com 
?resid=**X** <-- this should be your ID. 
&ithint=**file%2cxlsx** 
&authkey=**X** <-- this should be your auth key. 
&activeCell=**[SHEET]![CELL]** <-- Replace [SHEET] with the name of your sheet, then put an exclamation point, and the cell, for example **&activeCell=Sheet1!A10**

Hope this helps!

/ Seb