# Link to a specific Microsoft 365 Excel sheet

Tags: spreadsheet, hyperlink, microsoft-excel-365

Can I construct a link from a website to a specific sheet (called Admin) or a named range (called Status) in a workbook originally created by Microsoft 365 Forms in my account?

I have a share link which does successfully provide my team with access to the spreadsheet but doesn't go to the specific Admin worksheet. The link is currently in the following format:
https://MYORGANISATION-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/MYUSERNAME/ENCRYPTEDSTRING?e=RANDOMSTRING

I saw the guidance at [Specify a specific worksheet to open for a Microsoft Excel workbook using a hyperlink](https://superuser.com/questions/205728/specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-using-a-hype) and tried out the following options:

https://MYORGANISATION-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/MYUSERNAME/ENCRYPTEDSTRING#Admin!A1?e=RANDOMSTRING

https://MYORGANISATION-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/MYUSERNAME/ENCRYPTEDSTRING?e=RANDOMSTRING#Admin!A1

The link still works but still reverts to the Form1 worksheet which has been most recently been edited rather than the Admin sheet to which I want to direct my team.

Comment: Try to add the parameter like `activeCell=%27sheetname%27!A1`.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc 
When I followed your advice (after a holiday) I constructed the link as: https://sheffieldhallam-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ltismd_hallam_shu_ac_uk/EW8jKJxIQAVHlHXy_rRbUTEBYq7ZiYuA6yng7qg-0hcAuw?e=A1m5cz&activeCell=%27Admin%27!B7 , and that did work, but only briefly.   I saw it go to the B7 Cell on the Amin sheet, but I think there's an macro which then automatically makes the Form1 sheet active, so as to continue taking input from the related form.  And I don't want to override that macro, so I've come up with an alternative solution - see below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I modify Excel Online share URLs to open to a specific worksheet?](https://superuser.com/questions/804139/can-i-modify-excel-online-share-urls-to-open-to-a-specific-worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

Although I was able to follow the advice given and the amended link does open the Admin sheet at the specified cell, I think there's a macro which then automatically makes the Form1 sheet active, to ensure it will continue taking input from the related form.  I don't want to override that macro, so I've simply put a prominent button in the Form1 sheet to invite colleagues to go to the Admin sheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).